# How to check if docker-compose's "command" was executed

Tags: command, docker-compose

I've added

```
command: bash -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 4 -s  php:9000 -- bash run-ssh-on-php.sh'
```

to my docker-compose.yml

```
  php:
    build: docker/php
    user: "$LOCAL_USER_ID:$LOCAL_GROUP_ID"
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
      - mail
      - phantomjs
      - data
    volumes_from:
      - data
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    environment:
      - SYMFONY_ENV
    command: bash -c './wait-for-it.sh -t 4 -s  php:9000 -- bash run-ssh-on-php.sh'
```

and it seems that it wasn't executed at all, how can I check if it was? I tried adding "touch somefile" but nothing was created